# How to put in a bidimensional array, two columns of a csv list, for each field data

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a list with many fields, and i want to put in one multidimensional numpy array, two columns of the list for each different data in the first column or field.

For example:

```
model code price hall 

081  74  50  31    
081  65  55  32    
081  46  49  33   
081  88  45  34   
043  75  54  21   
043  75  54  21   
043  95  46  20   
043  99  47  23   
043  95  46  20   
.   
.
```

The required output is

for the model 081:

```
a = [[74,50],[65,55],[46,49],[88,45]]
```

for the model 043

```
b = [[75,54],[75,54],[95,46],[99,47],[95,46]]
```

in that order, because the object is to calculate some statistics with the arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) here to group the items based on the first item and then use that item as key to a dictionary and store the related columns in a list or NumPy array.

```
In [7]:  s = """model code price hall\n   081  74  50  31\n     081  65  55  32\n     081  46  49
  33\n    081  88  45  34\n    043  75  54  21\n    043  75  54  21    043  95  46  20    043  99
  47  23    043  95  46  20"""                                                                   

In [8]: from collections import defaultdict                                                      
In [9]: from operator import itemgetter                                                        
In [10]: from StringIO import StringIO                                                            
In [11]: from itertools import groupby
In [12]: f = StringIO(s)
In [13]: arr = np.loadtxt(f, skiprows=1, dtype=int)

In [14]: {k:[x[1:3] for x in g] for k, g in groupby(arr, key=itemgetter(0))}
Out[14]: 
{43: [array([75, 54]), array([75, 54])],                                                         
 81: [array([74, 50]), array([65, 55]), array([46, 49]), array([88, 45])]}                       

In [15]: {k:[x[1:3].tolist() for x in g] for k, g in groupby(arr, key=itemgetter(0))}            
Out[15]: {43: [[75, 54], [75, 54]],
          81: [[74, 50], [65, 55], [46, 49], [88, 45]]}

#If NumPy array is needed instead of Python lists.
In [20]: {k: np.array(list(g))[:,1:3] for k, g in groupby(arr, key=itemgetter(0))}               
Out[20]: 
{43: array([[75, 54],                                                                            
       [75, 54]]),                                                                               
 81: array([[74, 50],                                                                            
       [65, 55],                                                                                 
       [46, 49],                                                                                 
       [88, 45]])}
```

And a pure Python solution will use `collections.defaultdict` and the `csv` module:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open('foo.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    d = defaultdict(list)
    next(reader)
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        k, v = row[0], map(int, row[1:3])
        d[k].append(v)

print(d)
```

Comment: Thank you, i used the second version of your answer, it is very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.genfromtxt` and [fancy indexing (boolean masks)](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/array_object.html#using-boolean-masks):

```
In [587]: data = np.genfromtxt('a.csv', delimiter=',')

In [588]: a = data[data[:, 0]==81][:, 1:3]
     ...: b = data[data[:, 0]==43][:, 1:3]

In [589]: a, b
Out[589]: 
(array([[ 74.,  50.],
       [ 65.,  55.],
       [ 46.,  49.],
       [ 88.,  45.]]),
 array([[ 75.,  54.],
       [ 75.,  54.],
       [ 95.,  46.],
       [ 99.,  47.],
       [ 95.,  46.]]))
```